# Geocoder problam with the code

Tags: android, geocoding

i try to use Geocode but this code not working.
i need some api key from google or something ?
i already have a api key("Google Maps Android API v2").

```
public void geoLocate() throws IOException{ 
    String str = this.Serch.getText().toString();       
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> list  = list = gc.getFromLocationName(str, 1);
    Address add = list.get(0);
    String locality = add.getLocality();
    Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enable

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your manifest file?

Also, to test via an Android Emulator, you can use the DDMS and pass the latitude and longitude using the ‘Emulator Control’

You can also visit [this tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-get-address-with-street-name-city-for-location-with-geocoding/) about geocoding.